# Not able to delete a suspicious file from github repository

Tags: github, commit

I was trying to push **assignment6** folder in [this repository](https://github.com/mnauf/PIAIC-Assignments) and when I did and checked it, it wasn't uploaded and instead had this weird folder with the same name, which is empty inside maybe because it doesn't open.

I want to delete it. I tried `git pull origin master`, hoping that it will be downloaded to my laptop and I will delete it, but it says `repository is up to date`. In the end, I had to rename **assignment 6** in my laptop to **6assignment** and push it and it successfully did, but I still have that weird folder left in my repository.

Now, I want to remove  this weird folder.

Comment: Unrelated, but you _really_ shouldn't be publishing assignments in a public repo.

Comment: @jhpratt  have made it pubic for few minutes, to ask for help from stackoverflow

Comment: "and instead had this weird folder with the same name, which is empty inside"—did it have a grey icon? You probably had a repository inside a repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm -r --cached Assignment6
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository"
git push origin master
```

removed **assignment6** folder from repository.

In order to rename **6assignment** folder to **assignment6** in repository, repeated above steps again. Doing so, also deleted **6assignment**. Then renamed **6assignment** folder from my local machine to **assignment6**, and then pushed it.

P.S. Making the repository back to private now.